# How would i show $H$ is constant

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following problem.

If $H=\frac{P}{\rho}+\frac{v^{2}}{2}+gz$, Then $H$ is constant along streamlines

and if $\nabla \times v=0$, then $H$ is constant throughout the flow.

I don't really understand how to do this.

Comment: What about the proof on the wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Derivations_of_the_Bernoulli_equation

Comment: I dont see how i would do that

Comment: What are $H$, $P$, $\rho$, $v$, $g$, and $z$ and how do they relate to each other?

Comment: $P(x,y,z,t)$ is the pressure, $\rho(x,y,z,t)$ is the density $v(x,y,z,t)$ is the velocity and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity $z$ is the height, where the $z$ axis is directed up

Comment: It looks like the flow is steady, incompressible and inviscid?

Comment: @CheeHan That is correct sorry i should have added that.

Comment: This can be found in many classical fluid dynamics book such as Elementary Fluid Dynamics by David Acheson; see Section 1.3.

Comment: @CheeHan I have that book, i will have a look now. Thank you!

Comment: This is classical standard Bernoulli fluid pressure law. Please refer to several books in the library. It connects static and dynamic pressures with vertical column height if  it is a liquid.